# How to remove underscore character with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file as below:

```
This is an _PLUTO_
This is _PINEAPPLE_
This is _ORANGE_
This is _RICE_
```

I'm using below code to extract the output:

```
awk '{ print "Country: "  $NF }'  report.txt
```

Output:

```
Country: _PLUTO_
Country: _PINEAPPLE_
Country: _ORANGE_
Country: _RICE_
```

How do I remove all the underscore so that my output looks below:

```
Country: PLUTO
Country: PINEAPPLE
Country: ORANGE
Country: RICE
```

Comment: `substr` or `gsub` - see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Comment: sed -i "s/_//" report.txt

Comment: With that specific input `awk -F_ '{print "Country: " $2}'` would also work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this snippet:

```
$ awk '{ gsub("_", "", $NF); print "Country: " $NF }' report.txt
Country: PLUTO
Country: PINEAPPLE
Country: ORANGE
Country: RICE
```

Note that `gsub()` will perform the modification in place, so it will store the result of the substitution back to `$NF`, in your case.

If you're using GNU awk, you can use `gensub()` instead, which is slightly simpler:

```
$ gawk '{ print "Country: " gensub("_", "", "g", $NF) }' report.txt
Country: PLUTO
Country: PINEAPPLE
Country: ORANGE
Country: RICE
```

See GNU awk documentation for [gsub()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gsub_0028_0029-function-1) and [gensub()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1) for more details.

Comment: awk '{gsub("_", "", $0); print}' report.txt works as well. When print is called with no arguments, it prints the whole record, AKA $0.
Also, if you are using Solaris by any chance, you need to use nawk for gsub to be available. On Red Hat Linux 6.x, nawk is a link to gawk, which also supports gsub.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk -F_ '{ print "Country: " $(NF-1) }' infile
```

You could try `sed` instead.

```
sed -r 's/[^_]*_([^_]*)_.*/Country: \1/' infile
```

- `[^_]*_` matches everything until a first `_` seen.
- `([^_]*)_` matches everything after above match untill next `_` seen and `.*` matches everything after that, but only keep `(...)` part as a captured group.
- `\1` is the [back-reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html) to the `([^_]*)` captured group.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` instead:

```
$ sed -E 's/^This is (an? )?/Country: /; s/\<_//; s/_\>//' file
Country: PLUTO
Country: PINEAPPLE
Country: ORANGE
Country: RICE
```

This applies three substitutions:

1. Replaces the text `This is` optionally followed by either `a` or `an` with `Country:`.
2. Removes `_` at the start of a word.
3. Removes `_` at the end of a word.

The last two substitutions allows for data on the form

```
This is a _big_blue_ball_
```

which would be transformed into

```
Country: big_blue_ball
```

and not

```
Country: big blue ball
```

---

An `awk` alternative that just ignores the first part of each line and trims the first and last characters off of the last whitespace-delimited field:

```
awk '{ printf("Country: %s\n", substr($NF, 2, length($NF)-2)) }'
```

Comment: With `sed`, you can also simply use this:

`sed 's/_//g' report.txt` to delete all underscores.

If you want to change the file itself, you can do an in-line replace: `sed -i 's/_//g' report.txt`

Comment: @Larry Sure, but the _point_ I was making is that one may only want to delete the flanking underscores, and the rest of that field could contain underscores that should be preserved.

Comment: Indeed, that can be quite useful. If you want to restrict the regular expression so as not to touch possibly other lines, then it is also a good idea that you first filtered for lines of the required format (contains "This is a/an", etc.). Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Done by using python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
l=[]
k=open('file.txt','r')
for i in k:
        l.append(i)
m=re.compile(r'_.*')
for h in l:
        out=re.search(m,h)
        print "Country:",out.group().split('_')[-2]
```

output

```
Country: PLUTO
Country: PINEAPPLE
Country: ORANGE
Country: RICE
```